# Display all terms in the same lineage when user can save only the deepest level

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I'm using D7. I have a vocaburaly. User are enforced to save the deepest term in the vocaburaly with SHS(Simple Hierarchical Select). And, by the setting of SHS, user can save only a term on the deepest level.

Now, I'd like to view not only the term on the deepest level but also all terms in the same lineage of it as plain text. So I tried this using Views module. With views, I set "Taxonomy term: Parent term" in relationship and add "(Parent) Taxonomy term: Name"" in fields. But, it only can display only the parent level of the deepest level. I'd like display all terms including great-grandparent and more above levels. Can anyone give me a tip to do it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could https://www.drupal.org/project/views_tree be useful here?